# Orientation of KDP crystal to generate 4th harmonic using a Nd:YAG Q-switched laser and set temperature to stabilize crystal

Tags: optics, laser, crystals

I am setting up a 4th harmonic generator for a Q-switched Nd:Yag laser that will already have the second harmonic generator in place.  I need to know how to orient the KDP crystal with respect to the incident laser beam and at what temperature I should set its oven to. I am hoping there is a laser jock who can make quick work of these questions.

The KDP crystal has a graphite arrow on the top that points to one face and on the near side there is a graphite arrow pointing down.

[image: KDP crystal with graphite arrow on the top pointing to one face and a graphite arrow in the side pointing down]

The second harmonic generator is already installed on the laser, with a crystal tilt dial on the top.  A third harmonic generator is also shown in the picture but will not be used at the same time as the 4th harmonic generator.

[image: 2nd and 3rd harmonic mounted on the laser]

The simple scheme of the 4th harmonic (and 266 nm separating optics) is shown below.

[image: 4th harmonic general scheme]

Comment: typically its easier to ask the manufacturer what are the arrows pointing to. If crystal orientation, if coatings, if propagation direction.